# Find First Vowel Using Regex (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am attempting to create a pig latin converter which splits the string at its first vowel, and switches the first substring with the second (e.g. dog -> ogd).

The following regex code is working for single vowel strings, however when attempting to translate a word with multiple vowels, it is splitting the string at the last vowel:

`string.replace(/(\w+)([aeiou]\w+)/i, '$2$1')`

Running this code on the word "meaning" results in "ingmean" (splitting on the 'i'), whereas I am expecting to return "eaningm" (splitting on the 'e')

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to be specific about the *exact* output you are trying to get

Comment: @musefan I am hoping to return "eaningm"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the lazy (`?`) operator:

```
string.replace(/(\w+?)([aeiou]\w+)/i, '$2$1')
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
/([^aeiou]+)([aeiou])([a-zA-Z]+)/
```

And use

> $2$3$1